# Using Integrated Active Directory on an Azure DevOps release pipeline - "failed to authenticate"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dacpac

I'm using Azure DevOps to release my DacPac into a dedicated SQL pool. We are using MFA. However, when I try to use "Active Directory - Integrated" in the "Azure SQL Data Warehouse deployment" task, I am getting the following error:

[image]

This is a screenshot of my task config:

[image]

What do I need to do in order for my deployment to authenticate? I am an "owner" on the destination dedicated pool and configuring the release pipeline under my own login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Integrated" means that it uses the domain account running the process to authenticate. But since I expect you are running this on a shared agent that is not connected to your AD domain, that will not work. You need to most likely authenticate with either SQL authentication or Azure AD password authentication. The second option will not work if the user has MFA.

Comment: Thanks juunas. Neither option works for me:

SQL Auth - "Azure Active Directory only authentication is enabled"
Azure AD Integrated = "failed to authenticate" (as you say)

What is the best practice here? Do I need to ask sys admin to set up a user that doesn't have MFA?

Comment: Either that or allow SQL users (non Azure AD)